# Screen command for buffer

Tags: gnu-screen

I want to read the contents of the file into the buffer and stdout it to the screen. I did this:`screen -X readbuf /home/nitro/file|screen -X writebuf|cat /tmp/screen-exchange`but cat command showed me screen-exchange file with the previous result of readbuf command. If I do this commands separately - everything will be correct and I'll get the modified screen-exchange file.

How can I perform all three commands readbuf, writebuf and cat at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
screen -X eval "readbuf /tmp/x" writebuf && cat /tmp/screen-exchange
```